# Concatenating the first non primes to get primes

Tags: number-theory

When we concatenate the first 27 non prime numbers,we get a prime! i.e. 1468910121415161820212224252627283032333435363839 is a prime ! (beautiful!).  The concatenation of the first 50 non prime numbers is also prime! (146891012...6465666869). after these two I couldn't find any other prime up to the first 1000 non prime numbers .Could you help me to extend the searching? (I will except any verification as an answer to this question)

Comment: 1 is not considered a prime number by some authors. Otherwise I found your number here:[A241845](http://oeis.org/A241845).

Comment: IMO this question is rather uninteresting, because it is specific to base $10$. You would find different such concatenations on different bases. If you think about it, then each of these values is simply the value of some polynomial at $x=10$. And those polynomials aren't any more "special" than any other polynomial out there.

Comment: @mvw number 1 has additional property than the primes. So 1 is not considered as a prime,but best if we call it as 'unity'

Comment: @mvw but see that number 1 to the power of everything is still equal to 1. and no prime numbers have that property (for sure)

Comment: Obviously some guys are interested in similar sequences, see http://oeis.org/A104644.

Comment: Yes these are called Smarandache-Wellin primes:  2,23,2357,2357111317...719 etc.

Comment: If $P(n)$ is the number formed by concatenating all non-primes less than or equal to *n*, then the next prime of this form is greater than $P(4,000)$.